# btle central and peripheral no working ios8

Tags: ios8, xcode6, cbcentralmanager, cbperipheral

I had used Jorge Costa and Orlando Pereira tutorial here 
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-core-bluetooth-practical-lesson--mobile-20741

to create a little practice app to understand blueTooth le.  The app worked great under Xcode 5 and ios7 but now under ios8 and Xcode 6 it's a no go.  Has anyone else experienced this problem and does anyone know how to fix the problem of it works.